# App.vue mounting before navigation guards run

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

This a bit of a stretch, as I'd have to paste quite a bit of code to show my project setup. I am noticing that my `App.vue` file loads before my route file's navigation guard. This is causing a slew of weird issues. Are navigation guards supposed to cover the entire Vue app, or *just* routes? Is this normal?

*Notice* the log directly after

```js
router.beforeEach()
```

this logs AFTER `App.vue`.. which apparently it should not...

My `main.ts` file:

```js
import App from '@/views/App.vue'
import store from "./store"
import createRouter from './router'

const router = createRouter(store)
const UI = createApp(App)

UI.use(store)
UI.use(router)

UI.mount('#app')
```

My `route.ts` file:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      auth: true
    }
  },

];

export default function (store: any) {
  const router = createRouter({
    routes,
    history: createWebHistory(),
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
      return { top: 0 }
    }
  })

  router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    console.log('beforeEach')
    store.commit(`auth/setUseAuth`, to.meta.auth)

    if (to.query.state != null && to.query.state !== "") {
      ...redacted
    } else {
      ...redacted
    }

    // If the route needs authentication
    if (to.meta.auth) {

      // If we have a stored token, proceed
      if (hasToken()) {
        next()
        return
      }

      // If we DO NOT have a stored token

      if  ( // But we have a non-empty query code...
            (to.query.code && to.query.code !== "") ||
            // Or a non-empty JWT passed in...
            (to.query.jwt && to.query.jwt !== ""))
      {
        store.dispatch({
          type: 'auth/validateCode',
          payload: {
            ...redacted payload
          }
        });

        next()
        return
      }
    }
    // For all other requests, move forward
    next()
  })

  return router
}
```

Comment: I take it App.vue contains your `<router-view>`.  Vue Router's job is to replace `<router-view>` with the component related to the current route.  Your one route is for the Home component.  App.vue isn't a route itself, it's basically the container for your routes, so it will load first before the route guards run.

Comment: @yoduh correct. So really Home will be caught by my nav guard, not App. Is there any way to set up guards for `App.vue` even though it's not a route?

Comment: No, and it's not clear why it's important that App.vue load _after_ your navigation guards because App.vue isn't a route but just a container for your actual routes. It's your app's root component.  Everything starts with App.vue.  Explain your use case and maybe a satisfactory solution could still be offered.

Answer (score 2):

Navigation guards just cover routes.

It's not clear to me what the navigation guard is doing, as all paths end with `next()`.  (Note that `next` is [no longer recommended](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#Optional-third-argument-next).)  If you would like to redirect to a login page if needed, your navigation guard should do something like:

```js
router.beforeEach((to) => {
  if (to.meta.auth && !hasToken()) {
    return '/login';
  }
});
```

Comment: So `App.vue` should always render regardless of if I have navigation guards set up?

Comment: Yes.  Regardless of navigation guards, code in `App.vue` will run, its mounting hook will fire, and any content outside of the `<router-view>` component will render.